# SSRS 2016 Role Assignments

Tags: security, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have recently installed Reporting Services 2016 on a server.

When I try to add a user it only allows me to assign 2 roles to the user. System Administrator and System User.

I should be able to add them to Browser, Content Manager and Publisher.

Does anyone know where I can find these roles to add users to?

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem and I was looking in the site settings. To fix this I changed the security in folder settings.